# Androids AlarmManager wont trigger alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

i have an application that has an alarm system that works flawlesly and i copy all the 5 classes and just change the database name, but it;s not working, I can past u all the code but i want to hear if anyone had something like this before.

as I call new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mRowId,mCalendar);

the rowID is full(some number) and the mCalendar(has a date that i compare with the date from the Mcalendar of the other app that i have and it's the same format) and when i call this everything goes as it should it createse the pending intent

```
public void  setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when)
{
    Intent i= new Intent(mContext,OnAlarmReciver.class);
    i.putExtra(DatabaseIN.KEY_ROWID,(long)taskId);


    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when.getTimeInMillis(),pi);

}
after this nothing happens... can anyone help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean ur project->clean and if that doesn't help  create a new project and start writing the clases all over again.. that worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `when` has not happened yet (too far in the future) or it happened already (was in the past before your call to `set()`).

Or, perhaps you do not have `OnAlarmReceiver` defined in your manifest.

Comment: i have it 
  <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".OnAlarmReciver" />
            <activity

Answer (score 0):

PendingIntent.getBroadcast will reuse a matching pendingIntent, so perhaps it has fired that pending intent already (e.g., possibly from the code you copied it from), and since you're using a FLAG_ONE_SHOT flag, it'll only ever fire once.

Quick test is to remove the FLAG_ONE_SHOT flag, and see if it fires. If that is the problem, then simply use a different request code in the PendingIntent.getBroadcast.

Comment: what should i put instead of FLAG_ONE_SHOT?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to accomplish. If you only want to fire the intent once you can still use the flag, but the request code should be different for different intents (right now you're using 0, for probably more than one alarm, sounds like). If you don't actually need the FLAG_ONE_SHOT, don't use a flag (i.e., pass it 0).